# react js router route to outside router in nested router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested-routes

I have a problem with nested react-router-dom. I want to get out of inner router to outer router. I don't know how to explain it, so I bring a example here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-preventing-transitions-forked-vmt4c?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

What I want to do here is route back to '/' (BlockingForm component) from Topics component by clicking go root button.

How can I solve this?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Prompt,
  useParams,
  useRouteMatch
} from "react-router-dom";

// Sometimes you want to prevent the user from
// navigating away from a page. The most common
// use case is when they have entered some data
// into a form but haven't submitted it yet, and
// you don't want them to lose it.

export default function PreventingTransitionsExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Form</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/home">home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/one">One</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/two">Two</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact children={<BlockingForm />} />
        <Route path="/home" exact children={<NestingExample />} />
        <Route path="/one" children={<h3>One</h3>} />
        <Route path="/two" children={<h3>Two</h3>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

function NestingExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="home/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home/topics">
            <Topics />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Topics() {
  // The `path` lets us build <Route> paths that are
  // relative to the parent route, while the `url` lets
  // us build relative links.
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Topics</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/components`}>Components</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={"/"}>Go root</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/:topicId`}>
          <Topic />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

function Topic() {
  // The <Route> that rendered this component has a
  // path of `/topics/:topicId`. The `:topicId` portion
  // of the URL indicates a placeholder that we can
  // get from `useParams()`.
  let { topicId } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{topicId}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

function BlockingForm() {
  let [isBlocking, setIsBlocking] = useState(false);

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.reset();
        setIsBlocking(false);
      }}
    >
      <Prompt
        when={isBlocking}
        message={(location) =>
          `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}`
        }
      />

      <p>
        Blocking? {isBlocking ? "Yes, click a link or the back button" : "Nope"}
      </p>

      <p>
        <input
          size="50"
          placeholder="type something to block transitions"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setIsBlocking(event.target.value.length > 0);
          }}
        />
      </p>

      <p>
        <button>Submit to stop blocking</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the useHistory to manipulate the parent router (for react router v5)
reference:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

I've changed only the nested router in order to show you how to change the parent router location :)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Prompt,
  useParams,
  useRouteMatch,
  useHistory
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function PreventingTransitionsExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Form</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/home">home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/one">One</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/two">Two</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact children={<BlockingForm />} />
        <Route path="/home" exact children={<NestingExample />} />
        <Route path="/one" children={<h3>One</h3>} />
        <Route path="/two" children={<h3>Two</h3>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
    
 function NestingExample() {
//use useHistory hook to get the history context from parent router
  const history = useHistory();
//use this function on a onClick event instead of <link> to change the parent router
  const changeParentRouter = (url) => history.push(url);
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="home/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home/topics">
            <Topics />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

For react router v6, use the `useNavigate` hook:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function useLogoutTimer() {
  const userIsInactive = useFakeInactiveUser();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => navigateTo('/')}>
      Dashboard
    </button>
  </div>
}
```

Reference: https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.4/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tested routing using history but It worked same as before.